# jQuery FancyBox navigation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using FancyBox to view photos in my website. After opening a photo and navigating to next one navigation buttons dissapear and i get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: F.transitions[(intermediate value)(intermediate
>   value)(intermediate value)] is not a function.

Ive tried looking for missing semi-column but that's not the case.

```js
           switch (type) {
                case 'inline':
                case 'ajax':
                case 'html':
                    if (current.selector) {
                        content = $('<div>').html(content).find(current.selector);

                    } else if (isQuery(content)) {
                        if (!content.data(placeholder)) {
                            content.data(placeholder, $('<div class="' + placeholder + '"></div>').insertAfter( content ).hide() );
                        }

                        content = content.show().detach();

                        current.wrap.bind('onReset', function () {
                            if ($(this).find(content).length) {
                                content.hide().replaceAll( content.data(placeholder) ).data(placeholder, false);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    break;

                case 'image':
                    content = current.tpl.image.replace('{href}', href);
                    break;

                case 'swf':
                    content = '<object id="fancybox-swf" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%"><param name="movie" value="' + href + '"></param>';
                    embed   = '';

                    $.each(current.swf, function(name, val) {
                        content += '<param name="' + name + '" value="' + val + '"></param>';
                        embed   += ' ' + name + '="' + val + '"';
                    });

                    content += '<embed src="' + href + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%"' + embed + '></embed></object>';
                    break;
            }

            if (!(isQuery(content) && content.parent().is(current.inner))) {
                current.inner.append( content );
            }

            // Give a chance for helpers or callbacks to update elements
            F.trigger('beforeShow');

            // Set scrolling before calculating dimensions
            current.inner.css('overflow', scrolling === 'yes' ? 'scroll' : (scrolling === 'no' ? 'hidden' : scrolling));

            // Set initial dimensions and start position
            F._setDimension();

            F.reposition();

            F.isOpen = false;
            F.coming = null;

            F.bindEvents();

            if (!F.isOpened) {
                $('.fancybox-wrap').not( current.wrap ).stop(true).trigger('onReset').remove();

            } else if (previous.prevMethod) {
                F.transitions[ previous.prevMethod ]();
            }

            F.transitions[ F.isOpened ? current.nextMethod : current.openMethod ]();

            F._preloadImages();
        },
```

[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzCgJ.png)

Comment: Are you messing with the original js files? or the code above is your custom code?

Comment: No I'm not messing with a code, this is just a part of code where i get an error. It's on line  F.transitions[ F.isOpened ? current.nextMethod : current.openMethod ]();
This is original fancybox.js code